# NoneType: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_token'

Tags: python, azure, security, machine-learning, azure-sentinel

I'm using the Guided investigation - Fusion Incidents sample from Microsoft ([here is the sample link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel-Notebooks/blob/master/Guided%20Investigation%20-%20Fusion%20Incident.ipynb))

when i try to run this code in azure machine learning studio i got an error message says: ClientAuthenticationError: ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Although all the credentials are correct
Attempted credentials:
NoneType: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_token'

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
extra_imports = [
  "json",
  "bokeh.plotting,show",
  "msticnb,,nb",
  "msticpy.nbwidgets,SelectAlert",
  "msticpy.nbwidgets,Progress",
  "msticpy.context.azure.azure_sentinel,AzureSentinel",
  "msticpy.vis.entity_graph_tools, EntityGraph",
  ]

display(HTML("Starting Notebook setup..."))

import msticpy as mp

mp.init_notebook(
  extra_imports=extra_imports,
  additional_packages=["msticnb>=1.0"],
)
import re

def check_ent(items, entity):
   """Check if entity is present"""
   for item in items:
   if item[0].casefold() == entity.casefold():
        return True
    return False

def extract_resourcegroup(azure_id : str) -> str:

  azure_id = azure_id.lower()
  m = re.match(r'^/?subscriptions/[^/]+/resourcegroups/[^/]+', 
  azure_id)
  if m == None:
    return ""
  if 'providers/microsoft.devices/iothubs' in azure_id:
    return ""
  start, end = m.span()
  resource_group = azure_id[start:end]
  if resource_group[0] != '/':
    resource_group = "/" + resource_group
    return resource_group

def ti_color_cells(val):
  """Color cells of output dataframe based on severity"""
  color = "none"
  if isinstance(val, str):
    if val.casefold() == "high":
        color = "Red"
    elif val.casefold() == "warning" or val.casefold() == "medium":
        color = "Orange"
    elif val.casefold() == "information" or val.casefold() == 
  "low":
        color = "Green"
        return f"background-color: {color}"


def ent_color_cells(val):
  """Color table cells based on values in the cells"""
  if isinstance(val, int):
    color = "yellow" if val < 3 else "none"
  elif isinstance(val, float):
    color = "yellow" if val > 4.30891 or val < 2.72120 else "none"
  else:
    color = "none"
  return "background-color: %s" % color

def ent_alerts(ent_val):
  query = f" SecurityAlert | where TimeGenerated 
  between(datetime({start})..datetime({end})) | where Entities 
  contains '{ent_val}'"
  alerts_df = qry_prov.exec_query(query)
  if isinstance(alerts_df, pd.DataFrame) and not alerts_df.empty:
    display_timeline(
        data=alerts_df,
        source_columns=["DisplayName", "AlertSeverity", "ProviderName"],
        title=f"Alerts involving {ent_val}",
        group_by="AlertSeverity",
        height=300,
        time_column="TimeGenerated",
    )
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
# papermill default parameters
ws_name = "default"
incident_id = None
end = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
start = end - timedelta(days=5)
print(
"Configured workspaces: ",
",
```

".join(msticpy.settings.get_config("AzureSentinel.Workspaces").keys()),
)
import ipywidgets as widgets

```
ws_param = widgets.Combobox(
description="Workspace Name",
value=ws_name,
options=list(msticpy.settings.get_config("AzureSentinel.Workspaces").keys()),)




from msticpy.context.azure import MicrosoftSentinel
from msticpy.common.pkg_config import get_config
config_items = get_config("AzureSentinel.Workspaces")[ws_param.value]

try:
   sent_prov = MicrosoftSentinel(sub_id=config_items["SubscriptionId"],res_grp=config_items["ResourceGroup"], ws_name=config_items["WorkspaceName"])
   sent_prov.connect()
except KeyError as e:
   print("ERROR")
```

the Error message is on this line: (sent_prov.connect())
this is the code sample that i use from Microsoft and everything works fine until the last cell that starts from the imports of (from msticpy.context.azure import MicrosoftSentinel
from msticpy.common.pkg_config import get_config).

Comment: `ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.` doesn't sound to me like the credentials are correct.  That sounds like the actual problem; the `AttributeError` is incidental.

Comment: Please, post full traceback, verbatim.

Comment: @Samwise The subscription ID and the Resource group and the Workspace name are all correct and from the azure portal so there is nothing wrong with them

Comment: The traceback is the full error message (you get a stack trace showing you all the function calls inside the one that failed in your code).